# Unknown column in WHERE clause using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to refactor some of my code in **CodeIgniter** and try to have the actual `SELECT` query statements in the model. However I am getting an error saying,

> Unknown column: XXX in where clause.

Here is my code for the `SELECT query statement` in **CodeIgniter**:

```
public function login_user($username, $password){

            $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '.$username.') AND (password = '.$password.')');

            if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
                return $result->row(0)->id;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: The two lines you have commented out should have worked, assuming your table in fact has `username` and `password` columns.  Can you post your table schema?

Comment: yeah. I commented out the code to try the actual SELECT statements in CodeIgniter. Here is my table schema:
Table:
users
id int(11) pk
username varchar(255)
password varchar(255)

Comment: The function looks perfect... are you sure that you are getting the error in the same line?

Comment: yes.. the line where in I am using the SELECT query statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make a few tweaks to that function.

- Use the query builder so in case you change you database at any point you have to make little changes. It will also auto escape your variables.
- Then if all you want is the ID its a really bad idea to select *
- Its also a good idea to give default values to those variables and check if they are ready to use in a query before doing so.
- Finally your else statement is actually irrelevant. You can just return false by default without that else.

Something like this:

```
public function login_user($username = null, $password = null) {
    if (is_null($username) || is_null($password)) return false;
    $result = $this->db->select('id')
        ->from('users')
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->where('password', $password)
        ->get()
        ->row();

    if ( !empty($result) ) {
        return $result->id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, @marcogmoteiro now that you mention it, i'll have that function and other of my functions so that i'll have a more better understanding of **CodeIgniter**